# Presenting a semi-transparent modal view from __block typeof(self) blockSelf

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, ios7.1

I'm stumped trying to make this work for iOS 7 but it works fine for iOS 8.

I have a transparent modal view being presented from a parent vc, which is part of a navigation view controller hierarchy. The modal view animates into place as expected but then the underlying parent view disappears.

After the modal view does its work, it is dismissed and I return to the presenting view controller. But I'd like the presenting vc to remain in place while the modal view is on screen.

I've tried almost all the suggestions from SO like setting the modal presentation style of the presenting vc, setting the defines context and so on but none of the solutions has worked for me.

Why is this so simple in iOS 8 and so hard in iOS 7?

```
__block typeof(self) blockSelf = self;

void (^completionBlock)(POJSONResponse *obj, NSError *err) = ^(POJSONResponse *obj, NSError *error) {

    if (error == nil) {

        // display a transparent modal view
        UINavigationController *navController = blockSelf.navigationController;
        ModalViewController *mvc = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
        [mvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];

        navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
        [navController presentViewController:mvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so hard in iOS 7 because `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext` was new in iOS 8.  If you want this effect in iOS 7 you need to do it all yourself.

See [How to present a semi-transparent (half-cut) viewcontroller in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125667/how-to-present-a-semi-transparent-half-cut-viewcontroller-in-ios), particularly the answer that shows how to use `UIModalPresentationCustom` with a custom `SemiModalAnimatedTransition`.